# DataSource.Error AnalysisServices: The XML for Analysis request timed out before it was completed.Timeout value:3600 sec

Tags: excel, ssas, sql-server-data-tools

After connecting to analysis server through excel,when I am trying to import complete data into excel getting error after being loaded few rows.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `ServerTimeout` server property to a value high enough for this operation to complete.  To do this, connect to the SSAS server through SSMS and right-click the instance name then select **Properties**.  Go the the **General** Tab, check the **Show Advanced (All) Properties** checkbox and find the `ServerTimeout` property.  This is set in seconds with the a default of 3600 (one hour) as seen in the error message.  Modify the **Value** column to be high enough to finish this task.  After changing the `ServerTimeout` property press **OK** and this will be effective immediately with no restart necessary.  For more details on this and other SSAS properties review the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/server-properties/general-properties?view=sql-server-2017).  If what you're importing into Excel typically takes longer than an hour, you may want to look into another means of performing this such as SSIS.

Comment: Have similar error. It looks like it is client dependent error. The query runs from SSMS w/o any error.